# Periodicity of exponential function in a skew field

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, exponential-function, lie-groups

If an exponential function can be defined in a field $\mathbb F$ as:
 $$
 \exp(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} \qquad z \in \mathbb{F} \qquad (1)
 $$
 we can prove (using the binomial formula and the Cauchy rule for the product of series)  that
 $$
 \exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)\qquad (2)
 $$ 
and, if in the field there is an element $\tau \ne 0$ such that $\exp(\tau)=1$ than we see that the exp function is periodic with period $\tau$ because:
$$
\exp(z+\tau)=\exp(z)\exp(\tau)=\exp(z)
$$
and we can have also an element $\sigma= \tau/2$ such that  $\exp(\sigma)=-1$ and an element $\iota=\sigma/2$ such that $[\exp(\iota)]^2=-1$

The classical example is $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ where   $\tau=2i\pi$ and $\exp(\iota)=i$.

Now, if we use $(1)$ to define the exp function in a non commutative ring, the property $(2)$  is not valid in general, and we can have different elements whose square is $-1$,  as in the quaternion ring $\mathbb{H}$ where $\mathbf i^2=\mathbf j^2 =\mathbf k^2=-1$.

What can we say in this case about the periodicity of the exp function?

This question is connected to : [Periodicity of the exponential function in a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123077/periodicity-of-the-exponential-function-in-a-field) , that has no answer.

Comment: In most fields $F$, infinite sums don't make sense. In many fields $F$ neither does $z^n/n!$.

Comment: Yes, I see. But the question obviously refers tu situations where the serie is defined and absolutely convergent.

Comment: Perhaps a more natural context for this question is Lie groups rather than fields?

Comment: I add the tag. Maybe that we have to add a new tag as ''exponential-rings'' ?

Comment: The problem is you talked about this series being "absolutely convergent". This term is completely meaningless in the context of fields. Convergence requires at least a *topology*. So the least you need to give any sense to your question is a limitation to *topological fields* of characteristic zero. Even that restriction might not be enough, not sure.

Comment: You most probably need a field $\mathbb{F}$ which is *complete* with respect to some sort of *absolute value* (i.e. a metric space, or a ultrametric space, or something of the sort).

Comment: @Hamed. Thank you. But what about the question if the field ( and the ring) is such that the series definition  is correct?